# How can I set mongoDB profiling level persistently

Tags: mongodb, profiling

In mongoDB - I can set the profiling level in a shell:
`db.setProfilingLevel`

The thing is that when I restart mongod - it gets back to default values.

How can I permanently set it (probably in `mongod.conf` but I can't seem to find documentation on this)

Answer (score 5):

You can set it via

```
operationProfiling:
   slowOpThresholdMs: <int>
   mode: off | slowOp | all
```

Here is the link to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationprofiling-options)